# Adding exercise to Moodle course via SQL

Tags: mysql, moodle, moodle-api

I am trying to add large number of exercises to my course in Moodle 3.6 via SQL. First of all I created in Python command to execute:

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO `mdl_assign` (`course`, `name`, `intro`, `alwaysshowdescription`)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);'''
```

After this I successfully inserted data into database... but my course didn't change. I don't know what should I also change to make Moodle show added exercises in updated course.

Comment: It's been a while since I had to do this but if I recall correctly, you must also add corresponding entries to mdl_course_modules so that it actually shows up in the course. Documentation is sparse and the lack of an API makes it hard to do mass assignment imports.

Comment: Sadly it's not working. But thanks for answer.

Comment: @SamM Currently I am writing some Moodle webservice plugins. Looks like a nice idea. Maybe I could implement something that allow assignments mass imports. Send me a private message if you want to elaborate your idea.

Comment: Sam is right. You should add a coursemodule data. But it's much MUCH better to develop your own webservice which will create assignment modules for you, since core functions you will use in your webservice have events, capability checks, and a lot of things you cannot do by simply pushing data into DB